# What does <++> signify when using Vim LatexSuite?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I have a LaTeX editing environment that does some assistive stuff such as auto-indenting, closing parentheses, etc.

However, one of the things that it does is unknown to me, and is difficult to search for. If I type an empty set of braces, it replaces them with

```
{}<++>
```

If I type two empty sets, for example when I'm setting up a fraction `\frac{}{}` what I actually get is

```
\frac\left\{ } \right\}<++>}<++>
```

Is this a problem? What does `<++>` do?

Edit: This is using [Vim-LaTex / LaTeX-Suite](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=475)

Comment: It will help greatly if you provide information about the editor you use.

Comment: Have you opened your LaTeX document with another text editor to check if it really adds that to the file or is just some kind of markup?

Comment: @henrique Yes, it actually saves it in the file.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess this `<++>` is a regex pattern for the plugin in order to allow code completion. Like placeholders.

Comment: By the way, to get a fraction in Vim-LaTeX, you can type `\`/`,  which will insert `\frac{}{<++>}<++>`, placing the cursor under the first `}`.  That means you can just type the numerator, press `Crtl-J`, type the denominator, press `Crtl-J` again, and continue typing after the fraction.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Vim-LaTex / LaTeX-Suite for Vim adds these markers automatically and by intension. You can jump to the next such marker using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, which removes this marker. The idea is to speed things up by allowing you to jump to the end of the group or environment which was just added.
This is also useful for templates where you can add `<+name+>` markers which then can be also accessed using the above key combination to insert the content.

You should be able to deactivate the auto-insertion of these markers using the command:

`let g:Imap_UsePlaceHolders = 0`

Comment: To deactivate the automatic insertion of those markers: `let g:Imap_UsePlaceHolders = 0`