# What are the <++> in Vim latex-suite after typing in a bracket pair?

Tags: brackets, vim, vim-latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does <++> signify?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20829/what-does-signify)

In typing bracket pairs while coding, I usually type the opening and closing bracket before typing in the contents like so:

`\documentclass{}` <kbd>←</kbd> `article`

In Vim latex-suite, whenever I type in a matching pair, `<++>` shows up automatically. Picking up from the previous example, I'd get the following

`\documentclass{}<++>`

What are the `<++>` for? They also show up when I use `()`, `{}`, and `[]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It allows you to jump outside of the grouping operators by pressing `CTRL J`

When you press `CTRL J`, the cursor takes you to the position, deletes the `<++>`, and leaves you in `insert` mode, ready to type. Once you get used to it, it is a *very* useful device and huge time saver.

You'll also find the `<++>` device if you type `enumerate` and then press `F5` for example.