# Vim Latex \cite autocomplete <++>

Tags: vim

I'm trying out vim-Latex on a mac, and so far I like a lot of things about it, however the `\cite{}` command tends to give a `<++>` following it (yes, I can use the autocomplete, which is way cool). However, where can I tell it *not* to follow with `<++>`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It's actually the `{}` that gives the `<++>` which is ****very*** useful, as you can then jump to it by pressing `CTRL + J` see [What does <++> signify when using Vim LatexSuite?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20829)

Comment: Thanks! How odd, I haven't customized vim too much when I was coding, and only recently got into latex so I figured it was part of the latex package. I don't think <++> signifies anything specific in the package.