# Vim-latex adds extra brackets when typing empty brackets

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I just installed the vim latex-suite plugin.  Whenever I type empty brackets, parentheses, or braces, I get an extra pair of them, and I am moved to the middle of the new pair and put into insert mode.

i.e. after typing

```
{}
```

I get

```
{}{}
```

with the cursor between the second pair of empty braces.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout your vim setting of `backspace` via `:set backspace?`. If it doesn't contain `start` you should add this `:set backspace+=start` (help `:h 'backspace'`) to get the expected behavior of vim-latex.

Honestly, I think this should be noted somewhere in the vim-latex documentation or even set automatically by the plugin since it relies on it.

Comment: thanks!  This solved it!  though I am also now using the let g:Imap_FreezeImap=1 to stop it from moving the cursor to between the braces.

Answer (score 9):

Normally, you should have `{}<++>`, where `<++>` is a placeholder where you can jump using `Ctrl+J`. It seems like the delimiters for placeholders have been replaced by `{}`. From [the documentation of latexsuite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-place-holders.html), maybe you should verify the value of the variables `Imap_PlaceHolderStart` and `Imap_PlaceHolderEnd` to check whether these have respectively been changed to `{` and `}`. Maybe you could try adding the lines

```
let g:Imap_PlaceHolderStart='<+'
let g:Imap_PlaceHolderEnd='+>'
```

in your .vimrc. If you just want to get rid of the place holders, searching around, the question

[What does <++> signify when using Vim LatexSuite?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20829/what-does-signify-when-using-vim-latexsuite)

normally should give you a way to do that. Finally, I personally didn't like the automatic text replacement functionality, and I put the line

`let g:Imap_FreezeImap=1`

in my .vimrc. This deactivates lots of features, however in your case, the behaviour of `{}` should go back to normal. This however does not deactivate the automatic placeholder insertion, since pressing `Tab` in a `description` environment will introduce a `\item[<+label+>] <++>` in the document, which may also be corrupted in your case.

Comment: Thanks, though I should have mentioned I already got rid of the placeholders via the answer to that <++> question.  But I did end up using this to also get rid of the moving my cursor to between the typed brackets, which also solved the issue.