# Why does vim-latex sometimes insert <++>?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

Intending to use latex-vim's autocompletion environment feature, I hit f5, typed in "definition" and was greeted with

```
\begin{definition}


\end{definition}<++>
```

What does <++> mean?

Comment: Press Ctrl-J to find out!  Or take a look at [What does <++> signify when using Vim LatexSuite?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20829/106162)

Comment: IMHO it's more effective to type in `definition` and then hit f5 (one button press less).

Comment: @Skillmon, I press `:` then type in `definition` then hit `f5`. This does not work :c To use your trick, what must I do that I am not doing?

Comment: In insert mode just type in `definition` (as text) and then (without pressing space) hit f5. Also useful: With an empty document, type in `document` and then hit f5.