# Remapping keys while using vim-latex

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I am using the plugin vim-latex/vim-latex. It's a fantastic plugin for sure. But I want some of my own mapping to be there. Say whenever I press 4 I want $$ in return with the cursor on the second $, or whenever I press { I want {} in return with the cursor on }.

Earlier I added the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap 4 $$ < esc>i

inoremap { {} < esc>i

inoremap 0 <Esc>lla
```

The last one takes the cursor 2 steps to the right while in insert mode.

But these are not working now. What can I do to achieve similar functionality now? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion from Vim-LaTeX is to use [`IMAP()`](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/ls-new-macros.html) which takes `IMAP('lhs','rhs','ft')` which looks for `lhs`, replaces it with `rhs` when the filetype is `ft`.

For your two cases the following work

```
call IMAP('4','$<++>$','tex')
call IMAP('{','{<++>}','tex')
```

where `<++>` is a placeholder to indicate where the cursor should go (see the [vim-LaTeX documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-macros.html#place-holders) or [What does <++> signify when using Vim LatexSuite?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20829/106162)).

Personally I prefer to define an vim-latex environment as

```
let g:Tex_Env_m = "$ <++> $<++>"
```

which can then be called with <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> to produce inline maths.

---

Responding to the comment, non-insert mode stuff can be called using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> e.g.

```
call IMAP('3',"\<C-O>f{",'tex')
```

will temporarily use normal mode to execute `f{` which will find the next `{` and then leaving you with insert mode.

Comment: Thanks Dai. I had some other mapping too, like:
inoremap 3 llf}i
which finds the next } whenever I press 3 in insert mode, or
inoremap 1 A
which take the cursor to the end of the line in insert mode, or
inoremap 0 <Esc>lla
which take the cursor 2 steps right of current position.
I'm new to vim-latex, I'm not sure how to achieve these. Sorry if the questions are too boring.

Comment: @MahbubAlam I've added your first example which involves doing stuff beyond insert mode.  If that's not enough for you to define all the others you want yourself, please help me understand what aspect of the syntax isn't making sense to you.

Comment: Let me check my other remaps, I guess now I can manage. Thank btw. If I have some other troubles I'll let you know.

Comment: My remapping problems are solved. I was trying to use my earlier abbreviations. IMAP is interfering with abbreviations. I couldn't find a way online to resolve this. Can you help me on this issue?

Comment: @MahbubAlam what earlier abbreviations and how is `IMAP()` interfering?

Comment: I put the following line in a .vim file and sourced it while tex-ing:
iabbr resp respectively

So if i write resp and hit space it would automatically become respectively. Now while I am using latex suite, those abbreviations are not working.

Comment: @MahbubAlam hmm, I do seem toget issues trying to use `IMAP()` and `iabbr`, no idea what can be of use.  One thing though, I tried using your `inoremap`s and they seem to work fine with my vim-LaTeX setup - maybe there's something amiss with your setup, were you loading the `inoremap`s after vim-LaTeX/try putting them in an [`after` directory](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#after-directory)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74257/discussion-between-mahbub-alam-and-dai-bowen).